# UncaughtExceptionHandler to get all exception of the app

Tags: android, exception

I want to catch all unexpected exceptions in my app and log them.

So I implementend an UncaughtExceptionHandler (named CustomExceptionHandler) which logs exceptions to an internal database.

I also added the Exception Handler to my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends HomeActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new CustomExceptionHandler(getLogger ()));
  }
}
```

But to get all exceptions, do I have to add the exception handler to all my activitys and services? Or is it sufficient to have the exception handler registered for the main activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UncaughtExceptionHandlers are called by thread where exception is not handled. Activities and Services are not relevant in this process.
Handler set with setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler is called for uncaught exceptions in all threads of your app, except these threads where specific handler is set with setUncaughtExceptionHandler.
To answer your question - you only have to set default handler once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That saves a lot of work. :)